# Need reference for BSE/NSE[Indian] stock exchange api for fetching gold and silver prices

Tags: asp.net, .net, api

This needs to be specifically for indian stock exchange. If its a free one then its great but a chargeable one would also be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below links to get Gold and Silver prices :

http://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=10

http://www.FreeWebServicesX.com

From first link, you can get gold price by converting XAU to USD in webservice [URL](http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?op=ConversionRate).

In 2nd link you need to register and get gold price from [Page URL](http://www.freewebservicesx.com/GoldSpotPrice.aspx) :

Answer (score 0):

You can get EOD prices from the BSE and the NSE from [Intrinio](http://intrinio.com).

https://intrinio.com/data/bombay-stock-exchange-prices

https://intrinio.com/data/national-stock-exchange-nse-prices

It makes it easy to pull the prices for the entire exchange on a specific day:

```
https://api.intrinio.com/prices/exchange?price_date=2017-01-24&identifier=XNSE
```

If you can be more specific about the commodities prices you need it would help to give you an answer there. This is a [tutorial for Intrinio's API](https://intrinio.com/tutorial/web_api).